# How can I make these Google map markers filterable?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to work out how to make these Google Map markers filterable. The reason for this strange approach with the data not being fed in via an array, is because the markers are created from a Wordpress post query, and this is the only method that worked successfully.

I'm basically trying to get this to filter against a selected category, in a similar fashion to how you'd usually use: `for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {`

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

```
$('input.markers').each(function(){
        title       = $(this).data('title');
        description = $(this).data('description');
        lat         = $(this).data('lat');
        lng         = $(this).data('lng');
        url         = $(this).data('url');
        img         = $(this).data('featuredimage');
        comments    = $(this).data('comments');

        //var to the box that will wrap the marker's content
      var  content = '<img src="' + img +'" class="img-responsive" />' +
    '<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>'+ title +'</h3>' +
    '<p>'+ description +'</p>' +
    '<p><small>'+ comments +'</small></p>' +
    '<a class="btn btn-green" href="'+ url +'">READ MORE</a></div>';

        //create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map:map,
            title: title,
            icon: image,
        });

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var info = $('#marker-info');

    $('#marker-close').click(function() {
        $('#marker-info').fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Success! - Managed to turn it into an array.

```
var markers1 = $("input.markers").map(function() {

title       = $(this).data('title');
lat         = $(this).data('lat');
lng         = $(this).data('lng');
category    = $(this).data('category');
description = $(this).data('description');
url         = $(this).data('url');
img         = $(this).data('featuredimage');
comments    = $(this).data('comments');   

return [[ title, lat, lng, category, '<img src="' + img +'" class="img-
responsive" />' +'<div class="info_content">' +'<h3>'+ title +'</h3>' +'<p>'+ 
description +'</p>' +'<p><small>'+ comments +'</small></p>' +'<a class="btn 
btn-green" href="'+ url +'">READ MORE</a></div>' ]];

}).toArray();
```